# Make Vue.js not overwrite input field if it's filled

Tags: html, vue.js, twig, vue-component

In our code, we pass in a parameter and Vue.js uses that in the input field if the param exists, so far so good;

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" :value="customers_firstname ? customers_firstname : ''">
```

However, if the user makes an error (not filling in postcode etc) and this page gets reloaded, any changes they made to this field are forgotten. It defaults back to customers_firstname even if they edited it to be their mother's name or whoever they're sending this to.

How can I make this conditional, so Vue only fills the value if it doesn't have one already?

Comment: use a model not value="", do basic validation clientside, use ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Lawrence's comment, I was able to partially resolve this with v-model;

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" v-model="CustomerFirstNameAddressFunction">
```

However, the big thing causing resets was the paternity of the popover - so to make it fully persist, I had to access rooted vars;

```
computed: {
    CustomerFirstNameAddressFunction: {
        get: function() {
            return this.$root.customers_firstname_address;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this.$root.customers_firstname_address = value;
        }
    }
}
```

(Extra logic could be added to the getter, but it was simplest to instantiate the var with '' so that's why it loses the conditional bit.)

Answer (score 1):

use computed

```
computed: {
      CustomerFillName() {
      if (this.customers_firstname != null || this.customers_firstname !== '') return this.customers_firstname
      return ''
    },
}
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" :value="CustomerFillName">
```